# Why doesn't ng-if work?

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" ng-app>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p ng-if="1 == 0">True</p>
        {{1==0}}
</html>
```

I just made the simplest possible ng-if code.I would expect this to output

> false

but instead it outputs

> - True
> - false

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of angular? - Duh it's in your code. According to a comment on the documentation page, you'll need to use '"unstable" version 1.1.5' http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngIf#comment-990214083

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirmed [the comment on angular's documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf#comment-990214083) about using the unstable branch by creating this fiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p ng-if="1 == 0">True</p>
    {{1==0}}
</html>
```

[here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgqu5/) Running this fiddle results in the output you were expecting.

Your code, but with the unstable build.